Changing Segment Size in ggnetworkmap (GGally)
I want to plot a network of train rides in Europe on a map. In the GGally documentation there was a solution for a similar problem, but with flights (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GGally/GGally.pdf, Example on page 77ff).
Following this tutorial I was able to plot the network on the map with "ggnetworkmap". Now I would like to change the edge size depending on the passengers per train ride.
libraries used:
library(GGally)
library(tidyverse)
library(network)
library(sna)
library(sf)

The .shp file is from https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/statistical-units/territorial-units-statistics.
Settings: NUTS 2021, File Format: SHP, Scale: 20M, EPSG: 3035
I read the .shp file in:
map <- st_read("input/NUTS_RG_60M_2021_3035.shp")

added lon, lat:
map <- map %>%   
st_transform(crs = 4326) %>%
mutate(lon = st_coordinates(st_centroid(.$geometry))[,1],
       lat = st_coordinates(st_centroid(.$geometry))[,2])

and filtered for AT and DE:
map_filtered <- map %>%
  dplyr::filter(CNTR_CODE == "AT" | CNTR_CODE == "DE")

The vertices are in g_vertices_AT_DE:
   vertices
1      AT11
2      AT12
3      AT13
4      AT21
5      AT22
6      AT31
7      AT32
8      AT33
9      AT34
10     DE11
11     DE12
12     DE13
13     DE14
14     DE21
15     DE22
16     DE23
17     DE24
18     DE25
19     DE26
20     DE27
21     DE30
22     DE40
23     DE50
24     DE60
25     DE71
26     DE72
27     DE73
28     DE80
29     DE91
30     DE92
31     DE93
32     DE94
33     DEA2
34     DEA3
35     DEA5
36     DEB1
37     DEB3
38     DEC0
39     DED4
40     DED2
41     DED5
42    DEE01
43    DEE02
44    DEE03
45     DEG0
46     DE40
47     DEA1
48     DEA4
49     DEB2
50     DEF0

Added name, lon and lat to them:
g_vertices_AT_DE <- g_vertices_AT_DE %>%
  left_join(x = g_vertices_AT_DE, y = map[, c("NUTS_ID", "NAME_LATN", "lon", "lat")], by = c("vertices" = "NUTS_ID"))

This is an excerpt from the edges, called edge_filter:
# A tibble: 6 × 3
      c_unload c_load passagiere
      <chr>    <chr>       <dbl>
    1 AT11     DE11           50
    2 AT11     DE12           44
    3 AT11     DE13           13
    4 AT11     DE14           28
    5 AT11     DE21          112
    6 AT11     DE22            7

Converted edge_filter into a network:
edge_filter_network <- network(edge_filter, directed = TRUE)

and added lon and lat:
edge_filter_network %v% "lat" <- g_vertices_AT_DE[g_vertices_AT_DE$vertices %in% network.vertex.names(edge_filter_network), "lat"] 
edge_filter_network %v% "lon" <- g_vertices_AT_DE[g_vertices_AT_DE$vertices %in% network.vertex.names(edge_filter_network), "lon"] 

plotted g:
g <- ggplot(map_filtered, aes(color = CNTR_CODE)) +
  geom_sf()

and plotted the network on the map:
ggnetworkmap(g, edge_filter_network, size = 1, arrow.size = 0.25)

Now I would like to change the edge size depending on the passengers per train ride.
The argument "segment.size" seems to change the weight of the edges. I can change those to fixed values, like i.e. 0.5 or 2. How can I set the edge size for each edge individually?
Edit: This worked:
ggnetworkmap(g, edge_filter_network, size = 1, arrow.size = 0.25, segment.size = get.edge.attribute(edge_filter_network$mel, "passagiere"))

